# Is there any way to access Google Tasks on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

How do I access Google Tasks on my iPhone or, even better, sync them with the iPhone's Reminders app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider searching the App Store. A few that turned up were:

- [GoTasks (Google Tasks Client)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gotasks-google-tasks-client/id389113399?mt=8)
- [gTasks HD](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gtasks-hd-google-tasks-go/id428249408?mt=8)
- [GeeTasks, the Google Tasks App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/geetasks-the-google-tasks-app/id327744271?mt=8).

Comment: Please expand your answer. Three undescribed links is not an answer, it is spam, even if they're helpful. Please expand your "answer" to include the names of the apps you link to and why they'll answer the OP's request. I've downvoted your answer: edit the post and respond to my comment and I'll rescind the downvote.

Comment: Thanks for answering a question, Zac B! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. How do these apps solve the OP's question?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways to access Google Tasks is via the webapp. [Here](https://mail.google.com/tasks/iphone) is the iPhone version:

[image]

And [the standard basic HTML view](https://mail.google.com/tasks/ig?pli=1):

[image]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of native iPhone apps in the App Store that allow syncing with Google Tasks. They are better than using Google Tasks web site because they all allow offline access, so you don't have to wait for the web site to load.

In particular, I recommend the app that I myself wrote - [GeeTasks](http://link.memengo.com/applstex_geetasks).

I don't think you will find a way to integrate with Reminders, as there is presently no API published by Apple to access Reminders.